# Guardar values textarea en otro

Tags: php, javascript, html, qrcode

Estoy generando un **QR** con datos extraídos de una consulta, el **QR** 
y la consulta funcionan perfectamente.

El problema está que al guardar mediante **JS** los `values` en un `textarea` llamado "contenido" , se guarda:

```
Id de Reserva: 47cc04243419c598
Fecha de la Reserva: 
Hora de la Reserva: 
Número de Personas: 
Pedido: 
Importe de la Reserva:
```

¿Hay algún error en el código por el cual solo muestra el `value` de `idreserva`?

```js
$('#contenido').val("Id de Reserva: " +$('#idreserva').val() + "\n" + "Fecha de la Reserva: " +$('#fechas').val() + "\n" +"Hora de la Reserva: " +$('#horas').val() + "\n" +"Número de Personas: " +$('#persona').val() + "\n" + "Pedido: " +$('#pedidos').val() + "\n" + "Importe de la Reserva: " +$('#importes').val());
function htmlEncode (value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

 $(".qr-code").attr("src", "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=" + htmlEncode($("#contenido").val()) + "&chs=160x160&chld=L|0");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class=form-control>Id de la Reserva</label>
                                <input type="text" name="idreserva" id=idreserva class="form-date"  placeholder="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" readonly="readonly"value="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" >
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Fecha de la Reserva</label>
                                <textarea name="fechas" class="form-date" id="fechas" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['fecha']; ?>" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['fecha']; ?>"></textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Hora de la Reserva</label>
                                <textarea name="horas" class="form-date" id="horas" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['hora']; ?>" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['hora']; ?>" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Número de Personas</label>
                                <textarea name="persona" class="form-date" id="persona" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['personas']; ?>" value="<?php echo $fila['personas']; ?>" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Pedido</label>
                            <textarea name="pedidos" class="form-date" id="pedidos" cols="10" rows="5" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['pedido']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $fila['pedido']; ?>" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
                                <p></p>
                                </div>
                        
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Importe</label>
                            
                            <textarea name="importes" class="form-date" id="importes" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['importe'] .' €'?>" value="<?php echo $fila['importe'] .' €'?>" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
                                <p></p>
                                <p></p>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="contenido" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        
                            </div>
                       
                 <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="text-center">
<img
class="qr-code">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que pasa con tu código es simple, estas asignando el atributo `value` a los `textarea` de tu formulario pero dicho atributo no afecta el valor del mismo, para asignar un valor a un `textarea` directamente en el **HTML** debes ingresarlo en medio de las dos etiquetas (la de apertura y la de cierre), de igual manera esto no cambia el hecho que desde **jQuery** puedas usar el método `val()` para asignar o capturar un valor a un campo `textarea`.

Para mas información sobre `textarea` visita [HTML  Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional (sin tus etiquetas **PHP**):

```js
$('#contenido').val("Id de Reserva: " +$('#idreserva').val() + "\n" + "Fecha de la Reserva: " +$('#fechas').val() + "\n" +"Hora de la Reserva: " +$('#horas').val() + "\n" +"Número de Personas: " +$('#persona').val() + "\n" + "Pedido: " +$('#pedidos').val() + "\n" + "Importe de la Reserva: " +$('#importes').val());
function htmlEncode (value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

 $(".qr-code").attr("src", "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=" + htmlEncode($("#contenido").val()) + "&chs=160x160&chld=L|0");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class=form-control>Id de la Reserva</label>
                                <input type="text" name="idreserva" id=idreserva class="form-date"  placeholder="" readonly="readonly" value="00001">
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Fecha de la Reserva</label>
                                <textarea name="fechas" class="form-date" id="fechas" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="" readonly="readonly">04/07/2019</textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Hora de la Reserva</label>
                                <textarea name="horas" class="form-date" id="horas" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="" readonly="readonly">09:39 a. m.</textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Número de Personas</label>
                                <textarea name="persona" class="form-date" id="persona" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="" readonly="readonly">50</textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Pedido</label>
                            <textarea name="pedidos" class="form-date" id="pedidos" cols="10" rows="5" placeholder="" readonly="readonly">1</textarea>
                                <p></p>
                                </div>
                        
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Importe</label>
                            
                            <textarea name="importes" class="form-date" id="importes" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="" readonly="readonly">1000 €</textarea>
                                <p></p>
                                <p></p>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="contenido" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        
                            </div>
                       
                 <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="text-center">
<img
class="qr-code">
  </div>
```

Y así quedaría tu código sin eliminar lo de **PHP**

```js
$('#contenido').val("Id de Reserva: " +$('#idreserva').val() + "\n" + "Fecha de la Reserva: " +$('#fechas').val() + "\n" +"Hora de la Reserva: " +$('#horas').val() + "\n" +"Número de Personas: " +$('#persona').val() + "\n" + "Pedido: " +$('#pedidos').val() + "\n" + "Importe de la Reserva: " +$('#importes').val());
function htmlEncode (value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

 $(".qr-code").attr("src", "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=" + htmlEncode($("#contenido").val()) + "&chs=160x160&chld=L|0");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class=form-control>Id de la Reserva</label>
                                <input type="text" name="idreserva" id=idreserva class="form-date"  placeholder="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" readonly="readonly"value="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" >
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Fecha de la Reserva</label>
                                <textarea name="fechas" class="form-date" id="fechas" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['fecha']; ?>" readonly="readonly"><?php echo $fila['fecha']; ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Hora de la Reserva</label>
                                <textarea name="horas" class="form-date" id="horas" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['hora']; ?>" readonly="readonly"><?php echo $fila['hora']; ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Número de Personas</label>
                                <textarea name="persona" class="form-date" id="persona" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['personas']; ?>" readonly="readonly"><?php echo $fila['personas']; ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Pedido</label>
                            <textarea name="pedidos" class="form-date" id="pedidos" cols="10" rows="5" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['pedido']; ?>" readonly="readonly"><?php echo $fila['pedido']; ?></textarea>
                                <p></p>
                                </div>
                        
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <label class=form-control>Importe</label>
                            
                            <textarea name="importes" class="form-date" id="importes" cols="3" rows="2" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['importe'] .' €'?>" readonly="readonly"><?php echo $fila['importe'] .' €'?></textarea>
                                <p></p>
                                <p></p>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="contenido" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        
                            </div>
                       
                 <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="text-center">
<img
class="qr-code">
  </div>
```